# reading video from file opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Hi So I have written this code to capture a video from file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

//using namespace cv

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CvCapture* capture=0;
    IplImage* frame=0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromAVI(char const* filename); // read AVI video    
    if( !capture )
        throw "Error when reading steam_avi";

    cvNamedWindow( "w", 1);
    for( ; ; )
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if(!frame)
            break;
        cvShowImage("w", frame);
    }
    cvWaitKey(0); // key press to close window
    cvDestroyWindow("w");
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
}
```

Everytime I run it, I get the following error:

> CaptureVideo.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>
> CaptureVideo.cpp:13:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of having `char const* filename` you should put the actual filename (or a variable containing it), e.g. `capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("myvideo.avi")`

Comment: Ok I have used the name of the video I want but then I got this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Probably because you're throwing a `const char*` if the video fails to open... Make sure the path is correct and you have the correct codecs installed.

Comment: What exception can I throw instead?

Comment: You can throw any exception you like, but your problem is (most likely) that the video fails to open (for whatever reason, I outlined a few likely causes).

Answer (score 18):

This is C++ question, so you should use the C++ interface.

The errors in your original code:

- You forgot to remove `char const*` in `cvCaptureFromAVI`.
- You don't wait for the frame to be displayed. `ShowImage` only works if it is followed by WaitKey.
- I'm not sure if capture=NULL would mean that your file was not opened. Use `isOpened` instead.

I have corrected your code and put it into the C++ interface, so it is a proper C++ code now. My rewrite does line-by-line the same as your program did.

```
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
//#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using std::string;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string filename = "yourfile.avi";
    VideoCapture capture(filename);
    Mat frame;

    if( !capture.isOpened() )
        throw "Error when reading steam_avi";

    namedWindow( "w", 1);
    for( ; ; )
    {
        capture >> frame;
        if(frame.empty())
            break;
        imshow("w", frame);
        waitKey(20); // waits to display frame
    }
    waitKey(0); // key press to close window
    // releases and window destroy are automatic in C++ interface
}
```

Comment: We have to replace `if(!frame)` with if( frame.empty() )

Comment: I get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: @mkuse I think it is worth opening a question. I suggest you put there also the environment, the exact opencv version, c++ version and compiler you use.

Comment: @mkuse the question looks great, I don't have much experience with custom installed opencv on linux, sorry. I hope someone will help, after this thorough description. Good luck man!