# Process video frames

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame, video-processing

I want to develop an android app using OpenCV for detecting road lines. 
But I can't check it. So I need to read a video and process each frame, and I want to show it simultaneously . How can I do that? 
reading a video and get each frame in a function and return the processed frame and show that frame on the screen?

```
VideoCapture capture;
capture.open(R.raw.vid);
if (!capture.isOpened()) 
{  
     Log.i(TAG,"capture isn't open. closing..");     
}

for( ; ; )
{
capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
if(mRgba.empty()){
         break; }

Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);

ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);            
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

thank you

Comment: This is how it's done in OpenCV in C++. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709274/reading-video-from-file-opencv

Comment: In what language? You should tag it.

Comment: sry, I forgot, I want to develop an android app and using opencv4android in Native language (C/C++)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the bad news, but reading/writing video files from opencv is not supported on android ( due to missing ffmpeg backend there )

you'll have to come up with your own ( native ) solution for this.